# Unable to add "Done" button for PrimeFaces p:calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I had a "Done" button in `p:calendar` when I used PrimeFaces 3

I migrated from 3 to 8, and now the "Done" button is missing in `p:calendar`.

I tried the following:

```html
<p:calendar id="sdate" value="#{bean.sDate}" size="26" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" showButtonBar="true" buttonBarTemplate="{todayButton} {doneButton}"/>
```

It is not showing up and when I inspect it is not showing.
Note: no CSS/JS included in the page from out side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please first some off-topic issues:

1. PrimeFaces 8 is not the most recent version. The current version is 12, and 13 is around the corner (you can expect a release candidate soon).
2. Although I didn't find anything about your specific issue, but you should always consult the [migration guide](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide) when upgrading.
3. `p:calendar` is deprecated. It will be replaced by [`p:datePicker`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/datepicker/datePickerJava8.xhtml).

The answer to your question can be found in the [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/calendar). You simply need to set the `showButtonPanel` to `true`. The attribute's documentation states:

> Visibility of button panel containing today and done buttons.

Comment: thanks for the input i will check migration guide always.